# Can a modified Turing Machine be Turing-Complete if its Program and Data memory share the same tape?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

I've been working on a fun [esolang](https://github.com/CharlesAverill/GoFR#assembly-example) that operates under the idea that it only has program memory (an infinite, sequential list of registers that instructions and instruction arguments are loaded into). Any data needed for computation is loaded into a special `Identity` instruction - essentially, data and program share the same infinite memory tape.

I've been worried for a while that the language was not Turing-Complete because when instructions execute, their register "collapses" into a state with explicitly less information than before, so the program could only lose information over time.

I thought I had solved this problem with a `Move A B C` instruction that copied the registers from [A:B] to positions [C:(C + B - a)], effectively allowing for an increasing amount of information throughout execution.

However, I'm still not convinced that this model is Turing-Complete. It doesn't seem like you can build any abstractions without your abstractions being vulnerable to deletion. Put another way, it doesn't seem like you can abstract an immutable program memory.

My questions are - is it possible for this language to be TC given that its data and memory share the same space? Does a Turing Machine even need immutable program memory? Are there any instructions I could add to the model to resolve the issue?

The obvious answer is "don't have your instructions collapse after execution," but that's not really an answer to the question at hand, more of an engineering solution.

If it helps - [here's some IR I'm writing to try and build a self-replicating program to test for TCness](https://github.com/CharlesAverill/GoFR/blob/main/gofr/main.ml#L10).

Comment: It _sounds_ like you're asking is "can one design a Turing-complete language with a mutable program memory?", to which the answer is of course yes, but I suspect what you're _actually_ asking is "can I design a Turing-complete language where instructions are irrevocably overwritten after execution?". Is that correct?

Comment: @cody yes, that’s accurate